# Java не срабатывает repaint()

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Добрый день. Есть изображение, и методы paintComponent(Graphics g) и repaint(). Так вот: изображение рисуется только при если вручную менять размер окна мышкой, а я хочу что бы сразу. По идее для этого нужно поместить repaint() в конструктор, но это не работает(
Структура проги: основной класс MainWindow extends JFrame, из него создается класс GameField extends JPanel, и в этом GameField созданы методы paintComponent(Graphics g) и repaint(). Изображение рисуется внутри метода paintComponent.

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public  static  final double VERSION = 0.1;

    public MainWindow() {
        setTitle("... " + VERSION);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1024, 768);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocation(400,100);
        add(new GameField()); // it extends JPanel
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    }
}
```

Класс GameField:

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GameField extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private final int SPEED = 5;
    private int shipX, shipY;
    private int asteroidX, asteroidY;
    private Image ship;
    private Image asteroid;
    private Image shot;

    public GameField(){
        setBackground(Color.black);
        loadImages();
        repaint();
    }

    public void loadImages(){
        ImageIcon shipIcon = new ImageIcon("ship.png");
        ship = shipIcon.getImage();
    }

    @Override  
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(ship,500, 500, this); 
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `setVisible(true)` у `JFrame` нужно вызывать в самую последнюю очередь. В вашем же случае вы сначала заставляете фрейм отрендерится, а уже потом наполняете его содержимым, должно быть наоборот.

```
public MainWindow() {
    setTitle("... " + VERSION);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1024, 768);
    setLocation(400,100);
    add(new GameField());
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)